# How to delete wrong log schema in kaa application

Tags: kaa

During following my first kaa application, I added sample configuration schema to log schemas table by mistake. [log schemas table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw5Sw.jpg) How to fix the mistake ? I can delete neither application nor schema.

Comment: Place code snippet in question please - [ask].

Comment: There is no code. Please refer to the following web site.

Comment: https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/#create-schemas

Comment: Please don't refer readers to external sites.  Links become useless when they die or change.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to delete a log schema in Kaa. There is a ticket in Kaa Jira: [KAA-591](http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/KAA-591).

To correct the mistake, just ignore this log scheme and upload a correct one. Later in the guide, use a correct log scheme version to create an SDK profile.